# Can't find Fast switching BJTs

Tags: bjt, rfid, fet

I'm looking for a replacement for a FET switch that switches at 40 kHz. When the FET is on it is connecting an RFID antenna to ground.  When off, the antenna is open.  It does this in order to backscatter 915 MHz RF back to a reader. The FET is *not DC biased*. Very little RF current is going through the FET. The part # is SD 403 (Calmos)

The problem is the factory is blowing up too many FETs with ESD.  So I'm looking at BJTs or a less sensitive FET to ESD.  Would a BJT require biasing whereas the FET doesn't?

Any suggestions?  Thanks very much.

**Update**

First, thank you all for the replies. Those of you who asked how I know it's ESD, I don't yet know for sure. We do our own SMT in house
I don't yet know how to post schematics. Is there a common way you all do it?
I like the switch idea but hope to do a drop in or not have to bias it. Our current design connects the antenna directly to the FET Drain which also connects to the ASIC Antenna pin. The low-frequency Mod pin connects directly to the FET Gate. Source is grounded. No caps, no bias resistors. Battery RFID tag. Will a BJT work like that?

Comment: A link to the data sheet would be a good start.

Comment: I would be a somewhat concerned that the factory is damaging your components. Are you talking about your smt vendor?

Comment: How do you know ESD is the cause of the FET blowing up? Have you run tests with an ESD gun? It would help to see a schematic, is ESD frying the FET on the drain, source, or gate?

Comment: Agree with the other comments.  Why do you think it's ESD?  Maybe you're just putting too much power into the FET?

Comment: It's also important to figure out if the FET is breaking before it's put into the circuit or after. If it's afterwards, you should be able to fix that with schematic changes (and you should also talk to your vendor about their handling during assembly). If it's before, then you have a big problem with your SMT vendor that you need to fix.

Comment: You might want to consider an RF switch, rather than a discrete component. Check Peregrine Semiconductor, psemi.com, though several other people make the things as well. Connect the switch to the antenna through a very small C, it's only got to be low impedance at 915MHz, this should reduce its susceptibility to any ESD the antenna picks up.

Comment: The BFT93 and BFR93 or BFR91A are pretty fast BJTs with very low parasitics. But if you can tolerate some parasitic pF, 40 kHz is a cake-walk for common BJTs. And yes, get rid of your FETs (or else tell the factory to stop having people rubbing their feet on mats on cold days in order to have fun zapping your FETs for you.) The difference will be that the BJT will have a small stand-off voltage (some 10's of mV) where as your FET is more like a resistor than a tiny battery voltage. So you need to decide what works.

Comment: What is the FET part number?